# Force to change manifest file for installed PWA using IOS

Tags: progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

Is there a way to force changing the used manifest file of an installed PWA?

I have a file `manifest.json` that has the display `standalone`. Currently, every user that installed the PWA is using this manifest. However, because of iPhone bugs using the camera, I want to use a 2nd manifest file only for iPhone users called `manifestiphone.json`. This manifest only differs in the setting that the display is set to `browser`.

At the moment, I have the following code, that is working perfectly, if the PWA is not installed yet and will be installed:

```
$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(strpos($useragent, "iPhone")){
  echo "<link rel='manifest' href='manifestiphone.json'>";
}else{
  echo "<link rel='manifest' href='manifest.json'>";
}
```

However, it is not working for already installed PWAs. The code displays the right json for the iPhone but it is not displayed in browser mode. Any Ideas how I can force to use the new file or to display the browser mode without reinstalling the PWA?